# What is 貼地 and 離地

Tags: cantonese, colloquialisms, hong-kong

This is perhaps a colloquialism that i have seen many times in Hong kong youtubers eating and tasting food. My guess is that 貼地 means local? As in 地道？ what, then, is 離地？

May i also know the “etymology” of these words? I can’t seem to find them in dictionaries.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

“貼地” is like “down to earth”, or “keep one's feet on the ground”

“離地” is the opposite, “with one's head in the clouds”

there’s a place called “kennedy town” (堅尼地城) in hong kong. for most people, the pronunciation of “堅尼地” (kennedy) is identical to “堅離地” (absolutely disconnected with the reality)

further, another cantonese term: “陀地”, roughly means triad members “managed” area, or themselves, or protection racket.

have fun :)

Comment: Are these phrases Cantonese?

Comment: @r13, absolutely lah 